# The link to "Acceptable Use Policy" on public terms of service is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link, terms-of-service

In section 5, User Obligations, of [/legal/terms-of-service/public](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service/public), there is a link to the "Acceptable Use Policy" that points to [legal/content-policy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy).

Right now, this is a broken link.  The actual Acceptable Use Policy is found at [legal/acceptable-use-policy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy).

I see this issue on both Stack Overflow and Christianity.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. As you might have noticed, the legal pages moved from SE to SO. The SO codebase was missing a redirect, which is in place on [`https://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy`](https://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy).

A fix is rolling out in the next build (rev `2018.5.28.30533`).